# Methods for importing GeoJSON feature collection into ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geojson

I have a GeoJSON file containing a feature collection, with the structure/format validated by http://geojsonlint.com/.

What do people recommend as the best way to import this into ArcMap?  I have about 1000+ files that I need to import and was hoping to find/build a python script to batch import them.

I did try this toolbox:  https://github.com/jasonbot/geojson-madness, but I do get an error informing me that I have "Inconsistent geometry types", despite the the validation website informing me my structure and content is correct.

Comment: Which version are you on? Have you seen asShape? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000004m000000 it accepts geojson

Comment: ESRI shapefiles only accept one geometry type. so that message might be telling you that the geoJSON has multiple. (lines and points for example). [this should help with the conversion of inconsistent files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26662/selecting-feature-types-when-using-ogr2ogr-to-convert-to-shapefile) also take a look [at this script for batching many files in one directory](https://github.com/clhenrick/shell_scripts/blob/master/geojson-to-shp.sh)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found my method in ArcMap's Data Interoperability tools.  I had to install the extension, but then everything worked flawlessly, allowing me to import everything within whatever folder I specified with the extension".json".

It would be great to have another solution that didn't rely on the expensive extension that is only available to me under a 1-year student trial period.

Answer (score 10):

Use qgis, http://www.qgis.org , to connect to the geojson, right click on the layer, save as, and save it as a shape file. Then you can work with it in ArcGIS Desktop.  Alternatively, to work in batch mode, you can use the OSGeo4W shell that is installed with the standalone qgis installation to access the gdal/ogr toolkit to use command line ogr to convert geojson to a shape file as described at [GeoJson to ESRI Shapefile using ogr2ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68175/geojson-to-esri-shapefile-using-ogr2ogr) .

Comment: The OP specifically asked about automation. Can you edit your answer to include how to script or otherwise automate a solution in QGIS?