# Loading GeoJSON file into ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geojson

I am using ArcMap 10.6.1.

I have a GeoJSON file and I wanted to load into my map. I click on the add data option and go to the location where geojson file is stored. However, I could not see the geojson file located on the folder.

Am I doing this in the right way?

Comment: Have you checked [Methods for importing GeoJSON feature collection into ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152031/methods-for-importing-geojson-feature-collection-into-arcmap)

Comment: @user2293224, do you have ArcGIS Pro or ArcGIS online?