# Export spatial data from SQL Server to ESRI shapefile

Tags: shapefile, sql-server, ogr2ogr, osgeo4w

I want to export spatial data from SQL Server to ESRI shapefile and I have an issue :

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" " C:\Users\sqlexport.shp " 
"MSSQL:server=PORT_7FMW8H2;database=testdbspatial;trusted_connection=yes;     
"-sql "select * from DRShape" -overwrite
```

> ERROR 1: Failed to create directory C:\Users\sqlexport.shp for
> shapefile datastore.
>
> ERROR 1: ESRI Shapefile driver failed to create C:\Users\sqlexport.shp

Comment: You have written the -sql parameter wrong so it is omitted. When it is omitted ogr2ogr believes that you want to convert all the tables that it finds from your server and for that it wants to create a new directory that would get one shapefile per table.

Comment: so how can i write it ?

Comment: Put a space chartacter before the dash of -sql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is the exact command copied from your terminal, you simply need to be more careful with the spelling; there are spaces between quotation marks and the output file string. Try and replace your command with this one:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:\Users\sqlexport.shp" "MSSQL:server=PORT_7FMW8H2;database=testdbspatial;trusted_connection=yes;" -sql "select * from DRShape" -overwrite
```

If you have multiple geometry types in the table then you need to see [Selecting feature types when using ogr2ogr to convert to shapefile?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26662/selecting-feature-types-when-using-ogr2ogr-to-convert-to-shapefile)

Comment: ERROR 1: Attempt to write non-polygon (LINESTRING) geometry to POLYGON type shapefile.
ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 1 from layer SELECT.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed

Comment: now i have 3 ERRORS instead of 2 :)

Comment: This error means that your table "DRShape" seems to contain both polygons and linestrings. They can't be saved into same shapefile. You must either sort the geometries by geometry type or use some other format that supports mixed geometries like GML or GeoPackage.

Comment: @aminebak well, *solve 1, get 3* is actually not the worst ratio in problem solving...,). you could try adding `-nlt POLYGON -skipfailures` to the above command (or LINESTRING if that is what you want). this will only process the given geometry type and skips all those that do not match (and other failures, make sure you double check that shapefile). in the end, your table has mixed geometries and cannot be converted into one shapefile as it is.

Comment: I'am new to this, but i have only two columns in my db "DRShape" : Region with names of states and geom " 0x000000000104AB530000285D348AE0D21540762BCD0 " with that kind of values. so i dont think i have both in my db

Comment: @aminebak those values are just hexadecimal representations of your geometries; the *geom* column **can hold different geometry *types***, like LINEs and POLYGONs together, and the error messages tell you that there are indeed two types together. a shapefile **does not allow different geometry *types*** together. with `-nlt POLYGON` added to the `ogr2ogr` command, you specify that your shapefile will be of type POLYGON, and `-skipfailures` will ignore all LINEs (which would otherwise lead to above errors).

Comment: @aminebak if you feel you don´t know what to do, consider opening a new question (since, strictly speaking, your question here has been solved); add as much detail about your table/data and your needs and the error messages with the command you used. also, *MySQL* has the `ST_AsText` function that will give you a more readable representation of your geometries (`SELECT Region, ST_AsText(geom) FROM DRShape`)...check what types of geometry there are. don´t forget to upvote/accept ,)

Comment: it work with -nlt POLYGON but i dont have the name of the regions anymore :/

Comment: @aminebak I'm sorry, but without knowing your data and in comments, it's just not possible to help you explain and solve those issues. ask a new question, add the exact command you use, where your data came from originally and the error messages...as much detail as possible.

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26662/selecting-feature-types-when-using-ogr2ogr-to-convert-to-shapefile for an answer to this problem

Comment: Make sure you have the extended sql spatial tools written by MS. Run your query with a where clause 'where geom.STGeometryType() = 'Polygon' (or 'Linestring" or 'MultiPolygon') depending on what you're trying to export. This will only export the one type of geometry from the table and should fix your issue but will drop features that don't match that type.

Comment: @BrianW. you are answering a question asked in comments to an answer to a question by giving an alternative for getting stuck at the same problem: the attributes are missing. the issue could be that the polygons actually have no attributes, but the lines. or sth. else entirely...

Comment: @IanTurton do the offered solutions there to get shapefiles with specified geometries rule out missing attributes (and using `-nlt ...` doesn't)? this might be a duplicate of a question asked in comments to an...see comment above...why adding up to this? you should rather protect this...or move the question from comments to a new post. or some other moderator magic...

Comment: Tbh this question is basically screwed beyond fixing

Comment: @IanTurton hehe...moderator used magic: 'final words'. I like. well, I'm out...

Comment: @ThingumaBob similar but not the same. ogr2ogr -nlt polygon won't handle a geometryCollection correctly(at least in my experience). I suspect his union aggregate is merging a polygon and a linestring into a single GeometryCollection and not handling the metadata correctly when it breaks that out. He may need to explode collections.

Comment: @BrianW. fair enough, and good thinking...I was just complaining about the form in this post. the question somewhat adresses the end of a chain of possible sources/reasons for wrong results...

Answer (score 0):

i did a join between 2 tables **departements2** which has all department with their id and geometry with **BM_REGIONFR** with id of department and region ( i have 5 region in each region many departement )

```
select 
    b.[Region],
    geometry::UnionAggregate(geom.MakeValid()) AS Geo -- Add Alias!!
into 
    dbo.DRShape 
from [dbo].[departements2] a join [dbo].[BM_REGIONFR] b 
on a.[code_insee] = b.[dep_2] 
group by b.Region
```

After that i wanted to export the shapefile with *OSGeo4w* in order to have the map with the right decomposition and thats the query i used

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:\Users\sqlexport.shp" "MSSQL:server=PORT_7FMW8H2;database=testdbspatial;trusted_connection=yes;" -sql "select * from DRShape" -overwrite
```

And i got these ERRORS

> ERROR 1: Attempt to write non-polygon (LINESTRING) geometry to POLYGON
>   type shapefile. ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 1 from layer
>   dbo.DRShape. ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed

Comment: Can you load the data into QGIS? You can always export it from there to SHP...

Comment: ladies and gentlemen, this is so much not the place to ask and discuss this...just you wait until a moderator comes along ,) @aminebak please ask this as a **new question**, let's keep this board like it's supposed to work. you'l get answers then, I promise

Comment: @ThingumaBob I'll be waiting!